# VBA Access Runtime Error 440 Automation error

Tags: ms-access, automation, ms-access-2007, vba

I am uncertain what is causing this error and would like some help understanding what mistake I made which caused it as well as help or suggestions on how to correct the issue
Below is a section of code that I am getting the error on.
The debug flags up on line 7 "Feb = (Me.BillRate * DayNum) * Me.Util_"

```
    Set dayRs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT WrkDays FROM WrkDays ORDER BY WrkMonth;")
    dayRs.MoveFirst
    Set DayNum = dayRs.Fields("WrkDays")
    While Not dayRs.EOF
        Jan = (Me.BillRate * DayNum) * Me.Util_
        dayRs.MoveNext
        Feb = (Me.BillRate * DayNum) * Me.Util_
        dayRs.MoveNext
        Mar = (Me.BillRate * DayNum) * Me.Util_
        dayRs.MoveNext
        Apr = (Me.BillRate * DayNum) * Me.Util_
        dayRs.MoveNext
        May = (Me.BillRate * DayNum) * Me.Util_
        dayRs.MoveNext
        Jun = (Me.BillRate * DayNum) * Me.Util_
        dayRs.MoveNext
        Jul = (Me.BillRate * DayNum) * Me.Util_
        dayRs.MoveNext
        Aug = (Me.BillRate * DayNum) * Me.Util_
        dayRs.MoveNext
        Sep = (Me.BillRate * DayNum) * Me.Util_
        dayRs.MoveNext
        Oct = (Me.BillRate * DayNum) * Me.Util_
        dayRs.MoveNext
        Nov = (Me.BillRate * DayNum) * Me.Util_
        dayRs.MoveNext
        Dec = (Me.BillRate * DayNum) * Me.Util_
    Wend
```

I am guessing based on how I built this code that I will very likely get a similar error on the lines of code which follow after the "Feb" line. So I want to understand this error more clearly so I can correct future occurances.

UPDATE
After working with Hans he pointed me to using the recordset.getrows method which accomplished the same process that I was trying to do with less headache. So thank you very much Hans

Comment: I would plead with you to re-name `Me.Util_`.  Use of underscore is certain to create problems, including perhaps the one you are dealing with.

Comment: I would think the line `Set DayNum = dayRs.Fields("WrkDays")` needs to go WITHIN the `While` loop.

Comment: Unfortunately the Me.Util_ is based on a field I have no control on renaming. 
Can you explain why the Set DayNum = dayRs.Fields("WrkDays") line should be inside the Loop?

Comment: Because `dayRs.Fields("WrkDays")` presumably changes with each new record, so you have to get it fresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, that particular error message is rather thin on details.

My first suggestion is to disable this line ...

```vb
'Set DayNum = dayRs.Fields("WrkDays")
```

Then wherever you use `DayNum` in the rest of the code, reference the field value directly.

```vb
'Jan = (Me.BillRate * DayNum) * Me.Util_  ' use the following instead
Jan = (Me.BillRate * dayRs!WrkDays.Value) * Me.Util_ ' .Value should not be needed here; use it anyway
```

However, I'm not confident that suggestion is the fix.  If it's not, 
set a break point on the `Feb =` line and investigate the status of the recordset's current row and the values of all the entities ...

```vb
While Not dayRs.EOF
    Jan = (Me.BillRate * dayRs!WrkDays.Value) * Me.Util_
    dayRs.MoveNext
    Feb = (Me.BillRate * dayRs!WrkDays.Value) * Me.Util_ ' <-- set break point on this line
```

In the Immediate window ...

```vb
' are we perhaps at EOF already?
? dayRs.EOF
' confirm you still get the same error with this ...
? (Me.BillRate * dayRs!WrkDays.Value) * Me.Util_
' examine the components
? (Me.BillRate * dayRs!WrkDays.Value)
? Me.BillRate
? dayRs!WrkDays.Value
? Me.Util_
```

Hopefully that effort will reveal something which can lead to the fix.

Comment: dayRs is a single field record set. Will that work with a recordset?

Comment: I can't think of any reason why it would not work in general, but your code puzzles me.  The best I can suggest is try it.

Comment: Yeah the best I can call it is an attempt at a possible solution. I am trying the stuff you posted right now to see what I can get working

Comment: Ok I had an idea but I am not certain how to do it.
is there a way to populate an array with the values from a table?
because that would much more easily solve my problem.

Comment: Please try the change I suggested first.  It should be a quick test.  Perhaps we can discuss other approaches later if needed.

Comment: Ok I have gotten some information on what is going on from the infromation you posted

"? dayRs.EOF
True"

Comment: Also "? dayRs!WrkDays.Value" came back with a Runtime Error 3021 (no Current Record)

Comment: Excellent!!!  Examine the recordset's data source as a new query in the Access query designer: `SELECT WrkDays FROM WrkDays ORDER BY WrkMonth;`  Perhaps it returns only one row?

Comment: just ran the query and it returns 12 records in the correct order

Comment: Whoa!  Then I don't understand how you can wind up at `dayRs.EOF` after only one `MoveNext` from the first recordset row.  I'm stumped, at least for now.  Sorry.

Comment: What if I moved dayRs.MoveFirst inside the loop? would that work?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43944/discussion-between-hansup-and-mr-finn)

Answer (score 1):

If you are merely looking for days (or work-days) per month, you may do better using VBA date functions.  For example, info [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/210448).

Your requirements may be more complex -- maybe the days for a given month is specified by the user.  In that case, you need to fix the loop structure.  `While...Wend` is advancing the cursor through the recordset, and so is `MoveNext`.

```
While Not dayRs.EOF
    ...
    dayRs.MoveNext
    ...
    dayRs.MoveNext
    ...
    dayRs.MoveNext
    ...
Wend
```

Try commenting out the `While` and `Wend` lines.  Does your code run the same?

Comment: I am not certain I understand what you mean.
my understanding is that the dayRs.MoveNext command tells the program to move to the next record in the dayRs Recordset. This is a section I had a lot of problems with to start with so I would be very interested in possible alternate solutions. 
I need to pull a series of values from the table where that recordset is pointed at (which is baisically working days of the various months) I need to then do the assigned math that you see on the lines between the dayRs.MoveNext to get those assigned. If there is a better way to go about it im all for it.

Comment: Does `WrkDays` have 12 records?  If so, it seems you want to determine billing per month.  I'm thinking there are indeed easier ways to handle this.  I wonder what data is in `Util_`?

Comment: Its a calculation of revenue forcast. Bill rate is what their billable time is worth. The "_" is the place holder VBA uses for the "%" symbol the is in the actual column name. Util_ is the % of their hours which can be considered "Billable" hours. so its Bill rate * (Working days of the month*40) * the % of Utilization which gives the forcast of the expected revenue production.

Comment: Does `WrkDays` have 12 records?

Answer (score 1):

This will work with exactly 12 records, or more importantly with less or more.
After a time you may find that you have more records.

```
   Set dayRs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT  WrkMonth, SUM( WrkDays )FROM WrkDays GROUP BY  WrkMonth  ORDER BY WrkMonth;")
   dayRs.MoveFirst
   Do While not dayRs.EOF
    DayNum = dayRs.Fields("WrkDays")
    SELECT CASE WrkMonth;
     CASE 1
      Jan = (Me.BillRate * DayNum) * Me.Util_daysRs
     CASE 2
      Feb = (Me.BillRate * DayNum) * Me.Util_daysRs
     CASE 3
      Mar = (Me.BillRate * DayNum) * Me.Util_daysRs
     CASE 4
      Apr = (Me.BillRate * DayNum) * Me.Util_daysRs
     CASE 5
      May = (Me.BillRate * DayNum) * Me.Util_daysRs
     CASE 6
      Jun = (Me.BillRate * DayNum) * Me.Util_daysRs
     CASE 7
      Jul = (Me.BillRate * DayNum) * Me.Util_daysRs
     CASE 8
     Aug = (Me.BillRate * DayNum) * Me.Util_daysRs
     CASE 9
      Sep = (Me.BillRate * DayNum) * Me.Util_daysRs
     CASE 10
      Oct = (Me.BillRate * DayNum) * Me.Util_daysRs
     CASE 11
      Nov = (Me.BillRate * DayNum) * Me.Util_daysRs
     CASE 12
      Dec = (Me.BillRate * DayNum) * Me.Util_daysRs
    SELECT END
   daysRs.movenext
   Loop
```